# Temporary redirect to another website

Tags: seo, iis7

I'm thinking during maintenance time at my website instead of showing "Maintenance Page" redirect to the same idea site. It takes some time up to 1 hour

And I'm thinking to use temporary redirect.

What is the negative side of doing that?

Comment: For implementation notes, you may find [Will “performing maintenance” page holder affect your seo and page rankings? If so, is there a better way to handle it?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4503/will-performing-maintenance-page-holder-affect-your-seo-and-page-rankings-if) to be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of SEO, I suspect that would be confusing to users. If they are expecting to see one website and then see another without an explanation what would they think? Wouldn't an explanatory message that the site is down for maintenance with a link to the other site be not only more transparent for users, but good for search engines as well?

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear. It will be a message "you will be redirected in 5 sec to our partner site"

Comment: Ahhh. That does make a difference. Make sure the redirect is 307 temporary redirect. You can do that with an HTTP header and still have the delay so it's both user and search engine friendly.

Comment: BTW why 307 not 302?

Comment: @Eugene "but popular browsers implemented 302 with the functionality of a 303 See Other."