# Custom 505 and SEO

Tags: seo, apache2, error, http-code-500

There is a PHP project that sometimes throws 500 errors, I'm making a customized 500 page so that people realize we are monitoring this event and we will fix the issues.

My question is related to SEO

Should I still send the 500 header? Or should I make it look like a normal page and just not index it or something?

Is it a bad idea to remove the 500 header and use a normal 200?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but [Will “performing maintenance” page holder affect your seo and page rankings? If so, is there a better way to handle it?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4503/will-performing-maintenance-page-holder-affect-your-seo-and-page-rankings-if) may be of interest to you. (*Do* keep sending the appropriate 5xx response code, in any case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google likes to know if your pages are having trouble. In doing so it can keep up-to-date information of your pages. If you send back 500 error, Google + your users will know you are having problems and come back later. I suggest keeping the 500 response fix up the issue.